# joomla dynamic drop down on registration form

Tags: joomla, registration

I have two drop down list on my registration page of sql type. they both fetch data from database. but my problem is that in second drop down list , i want specific data as per the option selected in dropdown list 1. how to do it?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities(well theoretically endless)..

1) You send the whole data on pageload and then filter it using javascript based on the first selection.

2) Use the ajax technique, where you send the ajax handler the selected value and then the handler queries the database and sends the relative data which you append on the second select in the runtime.

Note:- for larger tables the firstone is NOT Recommended.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i want to ask that is it possible in joomla, i mean to say is that i have used 'sql' type field of joomla and also dropdown list is defined in XML file , so can i do it ??

Comment: Not with the joomla default xml form technique, to implement the above method, you shall have to manually enter each fields in the form view, then you could use jquery(or plain old javascript) to make the ajax calls, to a view with a post or get request (both ways work) with a argument "format=raw" in the url.

Comment: Can you explain in brief the last part of your answer?? i.e "to a view with a post or get request (both ways work) with a argument "format=raw" in the url"